# Link in label doesnt open in new tab

Tags: html, label

I have a href link within a label, eg:

```
<label>I agree to the <a href="mysite.com/termsandconditions" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
```

The link works, but it doesnt open in a new tab. Is there a way to have this work when the link is part of a label?

Comment: This works for me in Chrome. Are you testing in a specific browser?

Comment: @JohnMurphy, yeah in Chrome (Mac OS) too

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me(Chrome browser):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <label>Try to open a new tab by clicking <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">here.</a></label>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you create a brand new HTML file and have only this code present and it works for you, I'd suggest that there's another part of your HTML(or JavaScript) that is interfering with opening a new tab when clicking the anchor tag.